# Error with Spring security framework 2.6.4 (NoSuchMethodError for getInterfaceMethodIfPossible)

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-security, java-17

After the update to Spring boot 2.6.4, I get this error while i try to call my rest controllers:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.reflect.Method org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getInterfaceMethodIfPossible(java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Class)'
```

The problem does not occur until 2.6.3

I tried to add:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvc
```

To my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class, but that produces no difference

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot 2.6.4 should be used with Spring Framework 5.3.16 but you are using an earlier version. You need to update your Maven or Gradle configuration to correct this. I’d recommend using Spring Boot’s dependency management to keep versions in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading spring-core version to 5.3.16 solved this issue.

Comment: I think this should be upvoted too. Definitely as @Andy Wilkinson suggested we have to upgrade the version, but upgrading the core version should be a good alternative without playing worh version compatibility.